# ASP.NET VS2008 Ajax Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax, intellisense

I am using VS2008 Pro and the problem is the following.

I need to add eg.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="Filter1" runat="server" ValidChars="AEIOU" TargetControlID="TextBox1"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

This problem is that `<ajaxToolkit........` are not being detected by intellisense.
I added the reference `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` but I still can't use them

Thanks

Comment: I guess the question is not complete.

Comment: Someone should close this...sort of incomplete here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you haven't registered the tagPrefix.

Try adding the following line to your web.config.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

This should go in the system.web section.  You may already have a pages/controls section defined, in which case, just add the "add" element to the control section.